# To store data-value(custom-attribute) of last three li tags clicked by user at any given time using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have Multiple answer question in my HTML page.
Like below
Example:

```html
<ul class="no-styles que-list que-checkbox" data-max-count="3" data-que>
          <li class="question" data-val="2" onclick="find(this);">Lorem ipsum dolor, consectetured do eiusmod</li>
          <li class="question" data-val="1" onclick="find(this);">quis nostrud exercitatio</li>
          <li class="question" data-val="2" onclick="find(this);">onsectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non nu</li>
          <li class="question" data-val="5" onclick="find(this);">dolorem ipsum Ut enim</li>
          <li class="question" data-val="0" onclick="find(this);">di consequatur? Quis autem vel eum</li>

</ul>
```

I would like to store data-value(custom-attribute) of last three li tags **clicked by user at any given time** using Javascript.

Kindly, please suggest me how to achieve this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: when to store li value ?

Comment: you can use an java script array for that. something like onclick="yourarray.push(this.getAttribute('data-val'))"

Comment: once the li is clicked by user @Bhargav

Comment: and where its store ?

Comment: @fernando could you please suggest me a way to find out last 3 li tags that were clicked by user.

Comment: use an array: arr.slice(Math.max(arr.length - 3, 1))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one of code

```js
var listItem = $(".question");
total = listItem.length;
for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
  if (i >= 2) {
    console.log($('ul li').eq(i).text()); //store last three li here where you want
  }
}

//or

$('ul li').click(function() {
  var index = $(this).index();
  if (index >= 2) {
    console.log($('ul li').eq(index).text()); //store last three li here where you want
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="no-styles que-list que-checkbox" data-max-count="3" data-que>
  <li class="question" data-val="2" onclick="find(this);">Lorem ipsum dolor, consectetured do eiusmod</li>
  <li class="question" data-val="1" onclick="find(this);">quis nostrud exercitatio</li>
  <li class="question" data-val="2" onclick="find(this);">onsectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non nu</li>
  <li class="question" data-val="5" onclick="find(this);">dolorem ipsum Ut enim</li>
  <li class="question" data-val="0" onclick="find(this);">di consequatur? Quis autem vel eum</li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an attribute to item when clicked inside find function

```
$("ul li").click(function(){
  $(this).attr("clicked","true");
})
```

And then with attr selector and array#slice you can try

```js
var vals=[];

$("ul li[clicked='true']").slice(-3).each(function(){
  vals.push($(this).attr("data-val"))
})
console.log(vals);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="no-styles que-list que-checkbox" data-max-count="3" data-que>
          <li class="question" data-val="2" onclick="find(this);">Lorem ipsum dolor, consectetured do eiusmod</li>
          <li class="question" data-val="1" onclick="find(this);">quis nostrud exercitatio</li>
          <li class="question" data-val="2" onclick="find(this);">onsectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non nu</li>
          <li class="question" data-val="5" onclick="find(this);">dolorem ipsum Ut enim</li>
          <li class="question" data-val="0" onclick="find(this);">di consequatur? Quis autem vel eum</li>

</ul>
```

Do not forgot to check there are at least 3 clicked items before executing.

Alternatively, you can add a dummy class on click and select with that class later.